# What does GetType() do in this statement?

Tags: c#, .net

In the following statement:

```
Stream stream = GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
```

What is the `GetType()` for, and how does it work exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Object.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the type of the current instance from where this code is written.

I guess the code would have been more readable if written like this:

```
Stream stream = this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource);
```

I am unsure about the exact implementation of this method, it just returns the exact runtime type of the current instance.

Comment: Current instance of what? Thanks.

Comment: Current instance of the object inside whose method this code is written. You know, there are classes, those classes contain methods, and the methods contain code such as the one shown in your question. There are 2 types of methods: instance methods and static methods. In your case it appears that this code resides inside an instance method. An instance method can be invoked only when you already have an instance of some class. So for example: `var instance = new SomeObject();` and then if you call `instance.SomeMethod()` and inside  SomeMethod you use `GetType()` this will return `SomeObject`.

Comment: That makes sense, because I copied the above code into a static instance and got the error "an object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property object.GetType()".  I have a console application, hence the static method.

Comment: Yeap, that's exactly why you are getting the error. This method is available only inside instance methods. So if you want to achieve similar effect, make the method an instance again and then invoke it on the instance of your program: `new Program().SomeMethod();`.

Comment: If you could humor me please - a static C# Main() is not an object, then, right? If so, what is it? Is it out of the OO realm then?

Comment: No, it's just a static method on the `Program` class. What makes it special is that when used inside a Console application it acts as the entry point of this application, nothing more - a simple static method.

Comment: I see - the program itself is a class, but because it has no instance, that's a moot point.

Answer (score 1):

GetType returns the type of the object. When done like this, you can imply

```
this.GetType();
```

which would return the type information for the class that the GetType() is being called from. The Assembly gets the information about the Assembly that the class object definition lives in, and the GetManifestResourceStream returns a stream containing a resource within the assembly. Usually this is used to get things such as an embedded image, icon, documents, etc..

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you, especially for adding "this" - have upvoted.